# MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1: Doesn't let me run GUI commands as root. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: linux, xorg, sudo, root

I use the PureOS GNU/Linux distro (based on Debian/Ubuntu). I installed XDM as my display manager. After I logged into a X session as root, I got a bug. I can't run GUI commands as root in a non-root X session anymore. I got error messages saying that my MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 is wrong. It seems to be related to the .Xauthority file or the $XAUTHORITY variable.

I saw in several forums in the internet several palliatives for the problem. To run `xhost` as non-root with its arguments in various forms; but this disables the authentication of the system, opening security vulnerabilities; furthermore, it has to be done every X session. To run `sudo -sE`; but it this preserves the non-root environments. To run `su-to-root -X -c [command] %U`; it worked. To run `ssh -YXC [user]@[machine-name] [command]`; it worked. But these are workarounds that doesn't fix the original issue.

`DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xhost +local:` didn't worked. Neither `su - root -c [command]`. Neither `touch ~/.Xauthority; xauth generate $DISPLAY . trusted; xauth add ${HOST}$DISPLAY . $(xxd -l 16 -p /dev/urandom); xauth merge .Xauthority`; it gave me the error `unable to rename authority file /var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/, use /var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/-n`.

After some research (in that the x11vnc package helped me), I just discovered that the file that contains the right magic cookie is `/var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/A\:0-[whatever]`. Strangely, copying it to be the new .Xauthority file simply didn't worked for the first time, but did in the second one. So I made an `export XAUTHORITY="/var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/A:0-[whatever]"` and this seemed to fix the issue. However, when I made an `export XAUTHORITY="/var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/*"`, it didn’t worked; but the strangest is that an `echo $XAUTHORITY` shows  the full file path.

Also, I erased both the .Xauthority file and the $XAUTHORITY variable from my non-root user, and rebooted my device, to see if it will have any side-effects on this account. Strangely, before the reboot, the non-root user can run GUI commands even without them. After the reboot, the $XAUTHORITY variable from my non-root user was pointing to `/tmp/.Xauth[whatever]`.

Also, I saw that in every time I reboot the computer, the non-root user receives a new magic cookie, that matches with the A:0-[whatever] file (an hexdump showed that they contained matching hex strings).

That raises a series of questions: why the root user stopped receiving from the system the random magic cookies? What process generates and delivers these magic cookies? There is a command for the root to generate the right cookies?

Comment: for me not. check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659362/how-to-generate-correctly-a-new-xauthority-file-for-a-display-missing-it-witho . Newest installations of debian make as default `easy` as hostname for whatever reasons. this created a lot problems for me. check sysctl.conf, set `kernel.hostname=NAME`, and populate changes in bashrc adding `sysctl -p --system -w`. Also, `cat .Xauthority` to check what is the hostname given there. But sysctl was not needed if i edit that here `sudo nano /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp3s0.leases` and change it.